# Why aren't search engines encrypting search queries?

Tags: encryption, tls, internet, search-engines

As you will know most search engines pass the search information url-encoded, i.e a get request with the parameters on it.

But given all the fuzz about security and surveillance, why aren't SEs encrypting the data just by sending it in a POST request body?

Comment: The question seems to be based on the assumption that URL parameters are not encrypted by HTTPS, but only the POST body. This assumption is wrong.

Comment: I see, where can i read about it? @SteffenUllrich

Comment: why do you think GET parameters are not encrypted?